# When I move selected nodes from a cylinder to bend it the edges seemingly randomly splay out everywhere

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

images of the problem:

The cylinder before being moved:
[image]

After moving the central loop on the x axis:
[image: The cylinder before being moved]

From a different angle:
[image]

Comment: Want do you want to do exactly and what did you do to get to this result (what shortcuts)?

Comment: I want to make the cylinder lopsided in the middle by moving the loop to the side

Comment: I grabbed the loop and moved it on the x axis to move it over.

Comment: I am following the donut tutorial this is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLw0HwphXO0&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=10    Timestamp: 3:49 - when he is making the sprinkle bended

Comment: Maybe try disabling snapping to face.

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: That solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you select the edge loop, you're only going to be moving those edges, so of course it'll warp the shape. You're in Edit mode. If you want to get back to Object mode, hit tab.

Comment: How would you recommend I stop the warping

Comment: I am following the donut tutorial this is the link: youtube.com/…      Timestamp: 3:49 - when he is making the sprinkle bended